# 3-d word puzzle

Tags: puzzle-identification

I"m searching for a puzzle I saw in the Sunday NYT years ago. It was two 3x3 grids connected with "pipes"

Total of 18 letters connected with "pipes" and you could travel from letter to letter via the pipes, forward or backwards to spell out words of at least 5 letters.

Anyone?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Puzzling. Can you add more details please, maybe a rough sketch of what you saw?

Answer (score 6):

It was 3-D World Hunt. See [this](https://archive.nytimes.com/www.nytimes.com/premium/xword/Dec1706.2.html) archived NYT page, reproduced in part below.

> December 17, 2006
>
> 3-D Word Hunt
>
> By Will Shortz
>
> [image: grid of letters]
>
> Imagine that the lettered balls in the three-dimensional grid at right are arranged in two vertical layers: U, D, I, R, A, L, P, H and E in front and M, E, N, O, T, S, A, C and W in back. Find as many words of exactly five letters as you can spell by following the rods connecting the balls. You may return to a letter and use it twice in one word (as the T in STATE), but you may not “stand” on a letter and use it twice before proceeding (as the T in LATTE). Plurals are fine. Proper names and prefixes are prohibited. Finding 25 words is par; 35 is expert; 45 is genius-level. Our answer list, containing 51 relatively familiar words and five not-so-common ones — all from Merriam-Webster’s Collegiate Dictionary, 11th edition — will be shown next week.